# How to transform a string field into an array in Elastic to use on the dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Currently Elastic does not accept array-type `fields`, so on the frontend I had to do `JSON.stringfy` to convert my array to a string.

However, now I need to create a dashboard and use each property in this array, how can I do this?

I tried to script it in Painless Lab but encountered a series of errors.

[image]

[image]

**MY CODE:**

[image]

Comment: `Currently Elastic does not accept array-type fields` It sure does https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html

Comment: @Val Okay, I'm making an array of objects as in the aforementioned documentation, but how do I get each separate property from this array to be able to create graphs on the dashboard with them? Currently I can only get the "string".